# Runtime Error '5941' The Requested Member of Collection Does Not Exist

Tags: vba, ms-word

When running the macro I am getting the following error:

> "Runtime Error '5941' The Requested Member of Collection Does Not Exist"

The line below is highlighted in Yellow; This Macro works on the majority of users and the error has only been reported off two users.

```
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fCustomer").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fCust").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text
```

Any Help Would Be Much Appreciated.

```
Sub PopulateBookingForm()

Dim SourceTemplateName As String, DestTemplateName As String

' Set Method Statement Name
SourceTemplateName = ActiveDocument.Name

' Open Heavy Cranes ICO Booking Form
ChangeFileOpenDirectory "\\SERVERSHARE\HCD\HCD General\Templates\"
Documents.Open FileName:= _
    "\\SERVERSHARE\HCD\HCD General\Templates\Heavy Cranes ICO Booking Form.docx", _
    ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
    PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
    WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:= _
    wdOpenFormatAuto, XMLTransform:=""
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

' Set Haulage Booking Form Document Name
DestTemplateName = ActiveDocument.Name

' ### START FIND AND REPLACE

' Populate Customer(Client)
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fCustomer").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fCust").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Version
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fVersion").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fRevision").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Entered Onto CRM
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fEnteredOntoCRM").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fEnteredOntoCRM").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate CRM Opportunity Name
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fCRMOportunityName").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fCRMOportunityName").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Contact Name
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fContactName").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fSiteContact").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Telephone No (Mobile)

If Replace(Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fSiteMobile").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text, ChrW(8194), "") = "" Then
    Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fTelephoneNo").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fSiteTel").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text
Else
    Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fTelephoneNo").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fSiteMobile").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text
End If

' Populate Fax No(Email)
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fFaxNo").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fSiteFax").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Site Address
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fSiteAddress").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fSiteAddr").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Duration
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fDuration").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fDuration").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Date of Hire/RFW
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fTimeReadyForWork").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("dt1").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fDayDateOfHire").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("dt1").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Inspector
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fFormCompletedBy").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fACHSiteInspector").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fSiteVisitedBy").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fACHSiteInspector").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fMethodStatementBy").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fACHSiteInspector").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate CL
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fCL").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fTermsCL").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate CH
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fCH").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fTermsCH").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Wires
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fWires").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fAccessoryWires").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Web Slings
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fWebSlings").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fAccessoryWebSlings").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Beams
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fBeams").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fAccessoryBeams").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Chains
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fChains").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fAccessoryChains").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Shackles
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fShackles").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fAccessoryShackles").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Other
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fOther").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fAccessoryOthers").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Job Description
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fJobDescription").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fDescOfWorks").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fOperReqACHL").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' Populate Other Information
Windows(DestTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fOperationByClient").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks("fOperReqClient").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

' ### END FIND AND REPLACE

' Activate New Document
Windows(DestTemplateName).Activate
End Sub
```

The Macro Basically Copies Some Text From Fields In The Source Document Over To The Destination Document.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like those users are running your macro when the `ActiveDocument` does not have the `fCust` bookmark. You can add this test to your code before you try to use the `fCust` bookmark:

```
If Windows(SourceTemplateName).Document.Bookmarks.Exists("fCust") = False Then
    MsgBox "You are not using the correct source document. Failed to find the 'fCust' bookmark in " & SourceTemplateName
    Exit Sub
End If
```

On a side note, you can probably use a `Document` object to simplify your code.

```
Dim sourceDocument As Document
Dim destDocument As Document

Set sourceDocument = ActiveDocument
If sourceDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("fCust") = False Then
    MsgBox "You are not using the correct source document. Failed to find the 'fCust' bookmark in " & sourceDocument.Name
    Exit Sub
End If

Set destDocument = Documents.Open (FileName:= _
"\\SERVERSHARE\HCD\HCD General\Templates\Heavy Cranes ICO Booking Form.docx", _
ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:= _
wdOpenFormatAuto, XMLTransform:="")

   destDocument.Bookmarks("fCustomer").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = sourceDocument.Bookmarks("fCust").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text

... the rest of the code goes here
destDocument.Activate
```

Post your code to the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) part of SE to get a more detailed review of your working code.